# Realm React-Native Auth0: The provided credentials are invalid or the user does not exist

Tags: react-native, authentication, realm, auth0

I have started using Realm not long and I am trying to integrate a authentication workflow inside my RN app, using various tutorials, documentations. (I was using the nickname provider until now).

So at the moment, from the app, I can click on login, set my email/password and that user will be send to auth0.
But I can't manage to add that user into my Realm. And keep having that error:

"{"type":"https://docs.realm.io/server/troubleshoot/errors#invalid-credentials","title":"The provided credentials are invalid or the user does not exist.","status":401,"detail":"jwt malformed","code":611}"

Here is my Login function:

```js
login = () => {
  auth0.webAuth
    .authorize({
      scope: Config.AUTHO_SCOPE,
      audience: Config.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      device: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
      prompt: "login"
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res: ")
      console.log(res)
      auth0.auth
        .userInfo({
          token: res.accessToken
        })
        .then(data => {
          //Error is here
          const user = Realm.Sync.User.login(SERVER_URL, Realm.Sync.Credentials.jwt(res.accessToken))
          this.onAuthenticated(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("err: ");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });

      SInfo.setItem("accessToken", res.accessToken, {});
      SInfo.setItem("refreshToken", res.refreshToken, {});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error occurrdzz");
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

I am sure I am making mistakes, I think I didn't get all the steps to make an authentication works..

Anyway, thank you all for your help, I hope I've been precise enough !